# Why the command in a file fails to work ? (FreeBSD 10.2)

Tags: shell, freebsd, pwd

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bu3_RzzEiVo

My intention is to experiment with shell scripts in a file. (FreeBSD 10.2)

I create a file named script.sh

```
cat > script.sh
set dir = `pwd`
echo The date today is `date`
echo The current directory is $dir
[Ctrl-d]
```

After giving it execution authority, I run the command

```
sh script.sh
```

I get

[image]

Why the directory is not displayed?

Then I make a change.

```
   cat > script.sh
    set dir = `pwd`
    echo The date today is `date`
    echo The current directory is `pwd`
    [Ctrl-d]
```

This time , it works fine. The directory is shown successfully.

[image]

I would like to know why ? Could anyone tell me ?

Answer (score 3):

The answer from TessellatingHeckler was on the right track.

From the man page for `sh(1)`:

```
 set [-/+abCEefIimnpTuVvx] [-/+o longname] [-c string] [-- arg ...]
         The set command performs three different functions:

         With no arguments, it lists the values of all shell variables.

         If options are given, either in short form or using the long
         ``-/+o longname'' form, it sets or clears the specified options
         as described in the section called Argument List Processing.
```

If you want a *command* for setting environment variables, that command would be `setvar`, which you'd use as follows:

```
setvar dir `pwd`
```

This is, however, uncommon usage.  The more common synonym for this would be:

```
dir=`pwd`
```

or

```
dir=$(pwd)
```

Note that there are no spaces around the equals sign.

Note also that if you choose to use the `setvar` command, it's a good idea to put your value inside quotes.  The following produces an error:

```
$ mkdir foo\ bar
$ cd foo\ bar
$ setvar dir `pwd`
```

Instead, you would need:

```
$ setvar dir "`pwd`"
```

Or more clearly:

```
$ dir="$(pwd)"
```

Note that you may also need to `export` your variables.  The export command is used to mark a variable that should be passed along to sub shells that the running shell spawns.  An example should make this more clear:

```
$ foo="bar"
$ sh -c 'echo $foo'

$ export foo
$ sh -c 'echo $foo'
bar
```

One other thing I'll add is that it's common and unnecessary to use `date` as you're doing in your script, since that command is able to produce its own formatted output.  Try this:

```
$ date '+The date today is %+'
```

For date options, you can `man date` and `man strftime`.

Last tip: when using `echo`, put things in quotes.  You'll produce less confusing and more reasonable output.  Note:

```
$ foo="`printf 'a\nb\n'`"
$ echo $foo
a b
$ echo "$foo"
a
b
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: `set` *is* used for setting variables in `(t)csh` but not in `sh`/etc.

Comment: @EtanReisner, yes, but the OP is asking about shell scripts launched explicitly with the command `sh script.sh`, There's no mention of csh here.

Comment: That was added as additional clarification and I believe the default shell on \*BSD *is* csh (though whether `/bin/sh` is `csh` or just the default user shells I'm not sure).

Comment: There is indeed a `/bin/tcsh` in FreeBSD which is included in the base system, and `/bin/sh` is a POSIX Bourne-style shell that is is *not* csh.  FreeBSD's `/bin/sh` is based on the Almquist shell (ash), with a few additions.  As for the "default" shell, that would be `/bin/sh`, though most people switch to tcsh or install bash (which is not included in base due to licensing issues).